# How to make if statement on a file value if exist or not

Tags: php, file-upload

Hello guys I'm trying to do something
I have 2 files one is custom.js
and one is manage_menu.php

I have the html in custom.js which is this

```
jQuery("#main_menu_item_edit_div_"+menuid).html("" +

        "<form action='dashboard.php?p=manage_menu&edit=menuitem' method='post' class='form addmenuform' id='adnewmenuitmfrm' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" +
        "<center><img src='"+menuimg+"' alt='Avatar' class='avatar' height='200px' width='200px'></center>" +

        "<input type='hidden' name='rid' id='rid' value='"+menuid+"'>" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='menuid' id='menuid' value='"+mainmenuidd+"'>" +
        "<div class='col50 left twocll'> <p>" +
        "<center><input type='text' name='menu_name' id='menu_name' value='"+menuname+"' required='Name'></center>" +
        "<label alt='Name' placeholder='Name'>" +
        "</label></p> </div> <div class='col50 right twocll'> " +
        "<p><input type='text' name='menu_dsc' id='menu_dsc' value='"+menudesc+"' required=''>" +
        "<label alt='Description' placeholder='Description'></label></p>" +



        "<p><input class='uploadbtn' type='file' name='menu_img' id='menu_img' value='"+menuimg+"' required='Image'></p> " +
        "<p><input type='text' name='menu_imgs' id='menu_imgs' value='"+menuimg+"'>" +
        "<label alt='Item Image' placeholder='Item Image'></label></p>" +


        " </div> <div class='col50 left twocll'> <p>" +
        "<input type='text' name='menu_price' value='"+menuprce+"' id='menu_price' required='Price'>" +
        "<label alt='Price' placeholder='Price'>" +
        "</label><p style='margin-top: 0px !important'>" +
        "<input type='checkbox' name='outofstock' id='require_items' value='1' "+menuoutofstock+" /> " +
        "Out Of Stock</p></p> </div> <div class='col50 right twocll'> <p>" +
        "<input type='submit' value='Update Menu Item'></p>" +
        "</div> <div class='clear'></div></form>");
});
```

and in php file is

```
$id = $_POST['rid'];
            $restaurant_menu_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['menuid'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['menu_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $description = htmlspecialchars($_POST['menu_dsc'], ENT_QUOTES);

            $item_image = htmlspecialchars($_POST['menu_img'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $item_final_image = htmlspecialchars($_POST['menu_imgs'], ENT_QUOTES);

            $price = htmlspecialchars($_POST['menu_price'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $outofstock = htmlspecialchars(@$_POST['outofstock'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

and then

```
 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["menu_img"]["name"]);
                    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . 

end($temp);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['menu_img']['tmp_name'], './menuimg/' . $newfilename);

                $data = array(
                    "id" => $id,
                    "restaurant_menu_id" => $restaurant_menu_id,
                    "name" => $name,
                    "description" => $description,
                    "item_image" => "https://3marka.com/stores/menuimg/" . $newfilename,
                    "price" => $price,
                    "out_of_order" => $outofstock
                );
```

what i want is if the input file have value which is image upload and all fine if its already uploaded don't have to upload any file just save without generate random name with . like this 1651505616. that what happen when i don't put an image its just generate random name i want it to just do the edit with no edits on the image column

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_exists() method to make sure is file exists or not.

```
if (file_exists('./menuimg/'.$newfilename)
{
   echo "exists!";
}
else
{
   echo "not exists";
}
```